# Solve the following SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the SDE:

$$X_t=X_0+\int_0^t \sqrt{1-X_s^2}dW_s-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t X_s ds$$

I get no strong solutions but a weak solution (only one I was able to find):

$$X_t=\text{cos}(W_t),$$

I wonder primarily two questions:

1. Are there other weak solutions that distributionally differ?
2. Is there any solution that works for all real $X_0$ (the above solution requires $X_0$ is 1).

Comment: $X_t = \cos W_t$ sounds a bit misleading, since $W$ here is different from the $W$ in the equation. But it's a usual story with weak solutions, so ok. Concerning the initial condition, just take $\cos (W_t + z_0)$. Concerning the uniqueness in law, it must be possible to show that $\arccos X_t$ is (up to a constant) a reflected Brownian motion in $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: I tried $\text{cos}(W_t+\text{arccos}(z_0))$, but it did not seem to work, and would work for only $x\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: Of course. If initial condition is not from $[-1,1]$, then your equation is just ill-defined because of $\sqrt{1-X_t^2}$.

Comment: @zhoraster Correct. But I did not get it to work, since $sgn(sin(W_s+x_0))$ is not symmetric the laws do not agree.

Comment: @zhoraster Do you know if it is generally agreed that the Brownian motion in the weak solution can be non-centered?

Comment: Non-centered? No.